# Angular routing redirect to home when I use a good route for the first time

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I really don't know what's happened, but read carefully here my problem to understand it.

**NOTE : if you want to try and retry, use an INCOGNITO web page, and close it to retry**

I have a site with `some routes`, but what is bizarre is when I write directly the route for the first time it returns me directly to the home page, but once it's done. I can re-enter the same link or other link and it works. But Like I said the first time I use my link with parameters it returned me to home (`PagePrincipaleComponent`).

So for example,

**Step #1**
If I enter this (**link #1**):

https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/affrontement/p/e/177/55

It sends me to : https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/

But after I can re-enter the same **link #1** directly it works.

And I can try another link (**link #2**) and it works

https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/affrontement/p/e/175/176

And so on, (**link #3**)

https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/affrontement/p/e/9/1

But if you close your incognito browser and retry `Step #1`, and it will return to home page the first time (again).

My `app-routing.module.ts`

```
        import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
        import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
        import { TeamFranchiseListComponent } from "./team-franchise-list/team-franchise-list.component";
        import { PagePrincipaleComponent } from "./page-principale/page-principale.component";
        import { RecordComponent } from "./record/record.component";
        import { ConcessionComponent } from "./concession/concession.component";
        import { BourseComponent } from './bourse/bourse.component';

        const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: "",
            component: PagePrincipaleComponent
          },
          {
            path: "/",
            component: PagePrincipaleComponent
          },
          {
            path: "affrontement/:typeAffrontement/:affrontementEntre/:id/:id2",
            component: ConcessionComponent
          },
          // {
          //   path: "affrontement",
          //   component: ConcessionComponent
          // },
          {
            path: "teamfranchiseList/:choix",
            component: TeamFranchiseListComponent
          },
          {
            path: "records",
            component: RecordComponent
          },
          {
            path: "concession",
            component: ConcessionComponent
          },
          {
            path: "repechage",
            component: ConcessionComponent
          }
        ];

        @NgModule({
          imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
          exports: [RouterModule]
        })
        export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

So why a working link doesn't work the first time, but it works anytime after !!!

If you need some other code let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As note by Enrique your example #1 is missing a `/#/` from the url.

You are using hash urls which means that your webapp supports older browsers, but it's routing requires the hash in the url. See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

If you need to support older browsers there are at least a few option that you could do.

For example you could create a middleware in your application which catches the url and makes sure the hash is part of it before feeding it to the router. Or you could change the configuration of your web server routing rules to include the hash when it's missing, etc.

If you do not need to support older browsers, you can change the routing strategy to path based (see the previous link for more documentation on how to do that).

Comment: I can manage my routes to remove the hash. But I'm sure that will have the same problem. The first time a link is entered,the page is redirected to the home page. After it works with any parameters. So why the first time a browser goes directly to the page with parameters it is redirected to the home page !! very strange

Comment: That is due to the server handling redirection to the application and the application handling the sub-routing.
It sounds like the server rule for routing to your application is a wildcard that always redirects all calls to the main url: https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/. 
At that point the application cannot know anymore that there was a sub-url originally part of the url and cannot further redirect user.

Answer (score -1):

the thing is that the route or the link is wrong the route is like this:

https://lhjmq-web.nn.r.appspot.com/#/affrontement/p/e/177/55

the # is required

hope it's work for you

just let me know.

Comment: I just forget to Add the "HASH" in my first link. So I add it. Still have the problem